# code for the input of a sequence of numbers

Tags: objective-c

I'd like to write a simple OSX program using objective-C and Foundation:

Something like:
INPUT: Insert 6 numbers: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
RESULT: Your numbers are 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and your jolly number is 6.

What I can't do is the first part, how to insert more than one number (I would use NSLog e the scanf routine for the input)...
I know it's a stupid question for advanced users, but I'm just beginning.

Basically I'm trying to change this

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

@autoreleasepool {

int numero1;
int numero2;
int numero3;
int numero4;
int numero5;
int jolly;

NSLog(@"Insert a number");
scanf("%i", &numero1);

NSLog(@"Insert a number");
scanf("%i", &numero2);

NSLog(@"Insert a number");
scanf("%i", &numero3);

NSLog(@"Insert a number");
scanf("%i", &numero4);

NSLog(@"Insert a number");
scanf("%i", &numero5);

NSLog(@"Insert a number");
scanf("%i", &jolly);

NSLog(@"I numeri sono %i, %i, %i, %i, %i, il jolly è %i", numero1, numero2, numero3, numero4, numero5, jolly);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'd like to merge the input in a single input

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think the code would be different if you used Eclipse or `vi` and `make`. So, why the Xcode tag?

Comment: When you say OSX program, you really just mean a simple C program using the C API right?  You don't mean Core Foundation and Objective-C?

Comment: I mean objective-c and foundation yes, sorry I wasn't specific.

Comment: not homework 'cause I'm studying by myself, but yes, exercises...

Comment: Why NSLog / scanf ... go the extra mile and put some labels and a textField on a xib. When you'll get it figured out it will be worth it :).

Comment: Because that's what "the book" says at this very starting point :) it asks to use those...

Comment: i already know how to do some things in a more "advanced" way, but i'm trying to understand to code from the beginning

Comment: "merge the input" like what?

Comment: Instead of having a single input "command" for every number, I'd like to have the sequence in a single input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sscanf()` can accept multiple input, so perhaps:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

    int numbers[6];

    for (;;) {
        NSLog(@"Insert 6 numbers ");
        if (scanf("%d %d %d %d %d %d", &numbers[0], &numbers[1], &numbers[2],
            &numbers[3], &numbers[4], &numbers[5]) == 6) {
            break;
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"I numeri sono %i, %i, %i, %i, %i, il jolly è %i",
        numbers[0], numbers[1], numbers[2], numbers[3], numbers[4], numbers[5]);
    return 0;

    }
}
```

However this isn't really a Foundation program; you could replace `<Foundation/Foundation.h>` for `<stdio.h>` and `NSLog()` for `printf()` and it would work on any platform, not just OSX.

Comment: Exactely what I needed! The only thing I had to change is the last NSLog, the variables are numbers, and not number. Thanks very much :)

Comment: (Nitpick) In this particular case there is no *particular* reason to use an array, and @Ivy can use the original variable designations. An array is only useful if you run input, output, or both through a loop of some kind.

Comment: @Jongware And there is no particular reason not to use an array, however the array will come into its own when those numbers are sent around the program, which they are likely to be.  I'm sure Ivy will realize she can do either.

Comment: I'm in the boring phase of learning :) I'm not asked to find the best possible way to solve a problem, but just to do over and over again things in order to remember them and learn basic concepts... 
In this particular case I did the thing I was asked, but I wanted to make it a bit more simple